# Angular 2 two independent component share API data

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have third party API which share same data in between two independent component.

Let me say, the first component < A > and second component < B > both these component sharing common service data. Component < A > triggering API in button click and component < B > receive the data from common service. API will trigger only through component < A >. The component < B > is just consuming the response.

Here the issue is, how component < B > knows < A > button clicked and API triggered to service data updated.

Could you please let me know sample code. Here i am concern about performance impact while using EventEmitter.Here I expect best approach for large scale application.

My application based on angularCLI don't have any design pattern like Redux.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're providing the service from the same module source for the two components, the service will function like a singleton. In that sense, whenever a change happens in one component, the other component will know about it, because it shares the same instance of the common service.

Comment: Thanks. That's fine. Let me know, Do we need any 'ng' binding for component <B> html.